# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException - vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

can't figure out what went wrong with my code. I wanted to retrieve a sha256 key from mysql database.

```
keys table:
Id(int 4)    |  key (varchar64) 
1            |  5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

myAdapter.Fill(mydataatable) line keep throwing me error

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was unhandled
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   Message=You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'keys WHERE id= 1' at line 1

Here is the full error log:
http://pastebin.com/EG4GfywA

Here is my code, I learnt from youtube...

```
  Dim connectDatabase As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=testing123;Database=flag15")
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please input a user id", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE id= " & TextBox1.Text, connectDatabase)
        Dim mydataatable As New DataTable
        myAdapter.Fill(mydataatable)
        If mydataatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Label4.Text = mydataatable.Rows(0).Item("key")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("User ID is not found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            Label4.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need apostrophes around `WHERE id= ...`. However, you are wide open for [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Don't concatenate your sql string but use sql-parameters.

```
Using con = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=testing123;Database=flag15")
    Using myAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE id=@id", con)
        myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox1.Text)
        Dim mydataatable As New DataTable
        myAdapter.Fill(mydataatable)
        '...'
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I got an error in line 2..  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:

Comment: @ysj: Typo, corrected. I've mistakenly used the  `SqlDataAdapter` instead of the `MySqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: But here is the constructor that enables to create a `MySqlDataAdapter` from a `string`(for the `SelectCommand`) and the `MySqlConnection`: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter~_ctor(String,MySqlConnection).html

Comment: I tried adding a key column in other table but on the same db, it worked... But why it doesn't work on key table =x

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct to me. Try add ";" at the end of the query.

Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE id= " & Integer.parse(Trim(TextBox1.Text))+";", connectDatabase)

I've added a trim and Integer parse in case you are passing more blank character.

Try to log and post the FINAL query you are running.